# FileOpenPicker Bug

Tags: c#, uwp, xbox-one, fileopenpicker

```
FileOpenPicker. PickSingleFileAsync();
```

On Xbox One the above line opens a file selection screen however the cancel button on the screen is immediately deselected and the pages is stuck, you cannot go back.  Have to press home button then the awaiter continues.

Is all you have to do is call PickSingleFileAsync() for this to work on xbox?  There is no documentation for this use on Xbox specifically.

Comment: And your question is?...

Answer (score 1):

> however the cancel button on the screen is immediately deselected and the pages is stuck

I tested under the no file in the storage situation. Actually the cancel button can be selected, but not move the cursor directly to the cancel button by left or right stick. You need to press the "View button" o the game pad to focus on the file picker UI and then the cancel button will become focused, press "A button" will exit, the page will not stuck. The reason may be that file open picker has its own UI, details about open picker please reference [Open files and folders with a picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers).

For where is the "View button" please reference [Xbox One Wireless Controller](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/xbox-one-wireless-controller)
. The third button is "View button".

More details about unsupported features on XBOX please reference 
[UWP features that aren't yet supported on Xbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt693377).

Comment: thanks for that, I actually tested last night (not via visual studio), just ran the app with a thumb drive plugged in and it was fine, seems to be a bug when no filesource is available. I have read the supported and unsupported features of UWP on Xbox previously, thanks anyway. PickSingleFileAsync works and I assume so does PickMultipleFilesAsync, will test.

Comment: @Sixjac  I also tested under the no file source situation. Can work with view button.